# Clearing out a UITextField text and image

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextfield

I have this error code in place for my `UITextField`:

```
if (passwordStr.length == 0)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid Password"
                                                    message:@"You must enter a password."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    hasError = YES;

    [_password setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing];
    _password.rightView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rsz_logoblack.png"]];

}
```

I want to have code that later clears the _password `UITextfield` (no text) and gets rid of the right image and restore it to a default `Textfield`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
_password.text = @"";
_password.rightView = nil;
```

Comment: That's what I have, but is nil the proper way?

Comment: Well, it was nil before you set a UIImageView. So it would restore this property to the default value. I don't believe there is a method that would reset all the properties to default.